# How to disable some Rubocop inspections in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine, rubocop

I can't find any solution on how to disable some Rubocop inspections in RubyMine. Ex. the "use single quote string instead of double-quote".

And there are some other inspections that I would like to disable.

I tried going to the "Editor | Inspections" in the settings but you can't change it there.

I also saw that there should be a `.rubocop.yml` file somewhere but I can't find it anywhere.

It would be also cool if I could set it for every project rather than just this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RubyMine you can configure the inspection named 'String can be converted to single quoted'. As for Rubocop's configuration, yes, you need to use .rubocop.yml file, which isn't created automatically. Please refer to [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/rubocop.html#rubocop.yml) and [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Oh, so I have to create it myself in the project. Thanks!